# How to show this function is injective?

Tags: analysis

Define $h: \mathbb Z \to [0,1]$ by $h(z)= z \pi - [z\pi]$ where $[.]$ denotes the floor function.

I want to show this function is injective, I have tried both the approaches using $h(z_1)= h(z_2)$ and try to get $z_1= z_2$ and the another one $z_1\neq z_2 $ to get $h(z_1)\neq h(z_2)$ but stuck in both the methods.

Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $h(z_1) = h(z_2)$ then
$$
z_1\pi - [z_1\pi] = z_2\pi - [z_2\pi]  
$$
and so
$$
z_1\pi -  z_2\pi= [z_1\pi]  - [z_2\pi]  
$$
so
$$
(z_1 - z_2)\pi = [z_1\pi]  - [z_2\pi]  
$$
so \dots (I am sure you can figure out the rest.)

Comment: modulus of L.H.S is greater than $1$ but modulus of RHS is less than $1$. Right?

Comment: On the left hand side you have something that is an integer times $\pi$. On the right you have an integer, so ...

Comment: Oh okay, Silly me!

Comment: Thanks a lot!! L)

Comment: @User: You are welcome.